# Javascript multiple digit index

Tags: javascript, indexing

I have searched around the net and the solution must be so simple no one has asked? 
I just wanted to use an index like `+ i +` to return 001, 002, 003, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
('000' + i).substr(-3);
```

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?

```
function number_pad(num,len) {
    num = ""+num;
    while(num.length < len) num = "0"+num;
    return num;
}
// Usage: number_pad(i,3);
```

Alternatively, extend the native object:

```
Number.prototype.pad(len) {
    var num = ""+this;
    while(num.length < len) num = "0"+num;
    return num;
}
// Usage: i.pad(3);
```

For future reference, this is called zerofill or zero-padding.

Answer (score 1):

```
function paddedNumber(n) {
  // A string containing the fully padded zero value.
  var zeroes = "000";
  // The number as a string.
  var numstr = "" + n;
  var nDigits = numstr.length;
  // Keep any sign at the front.
  var sign = "";
  if (/^[\+\-]/.test(numstr)) {
    sign = numstr.charAt(0);
    numstr = numstr.substring(1);
  }
  // Concatenates the number with just enough zeroes.
  // No padding if itoa is already longer than the pad.
  return sign + zeroes.substring(nDigits) + numstr;
}
```